# Why is my replication lagging all of a sudden?

Tags: mysql, replication

We run a db.m4.10xlarge instance on AWS for our web app(s) and I've recently set up a read replica as a db.m4.2xlarge instance. We've been experimenting with smaller instances for a read replica but they couldn't keep up with the master. The db.m4.2xlarge had no trouble catching up with the master server within an hour or so - ready to go.

Then last night, something odd happened. Write activity on the replica dropped right down and now I can see the replica has drifted 2.5hrs or so from the master (we have constant write activity on one table with timestamps so it's easy to reliably check).

Does anyone know what the cause of this could be? I can't see anything at all in the logs - it's almost as though we've lost a write thread or something like that.. very weird.

Write IOPS last 24hrs:
[image: Write IOPS last 24hrs]

Replica lag:
[image]

If anyone can provide any pointers that'd be helpful. Both the master and replica are MySQL 5.6.34. No changes have been made since spinning up the replica.

Comment: The *only* thing I can think of is that we ran out of IOPS on our General Purpose (SSD) storage type, however that doesn't seem to match up with Amazon's documentation on the subject (I think?!)

Comment: Also note we run two busy databases on that instance, so perhaps setting slave_parallel_workers = 2 would help?

Comment: What cron job runs at about :30 after each hour?  The problem seems to have started at about 22:30.

Comment: Sounds like you got capped at 500 write IOPs.

Comment: Any ALTERs running?

Comment: @RickJames I don't believe we had any ALTERs running, however we may well have had some DROP TABLE, RENAME TABLE and CREATE TABLE's going on. There are lots of databases on this RDS server doing quite a bit of stuff, however there was certainly nothing out of the ordinary happening at 22:15 when the lag went nuts - we run the DROP, RENAME and CREATE's all day long. This is why I can only guess it's something to do with IOPS limit..

Comment: Is the Query cache turned on?  If so, what size?  Is there swapping?  That would cause lots of IOPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after much googling I discovered the issue was quite simply we had run out of IOPS to catch up with the master database instance.

The replica DB had 120GB of storage, and the baseline IOPS for RDS is 3x storage space, so in this case it was 360 IOPS.

Cloudwatch can tell you the burst credits you have remaining, and it turned out they were all used up right at the time the replica lag started. This was great as it confirmed my suspicion that we'd run out of IOPS (in addition to @Rick_James suggesting it..)

I've now upgraded the replica to 250GB which gives 750 IOPS as a baseline - based off IOPS when everything was working fine this should be more than enough to keep up with the master server. Also, it's not too expensive ;)

Replica lag after EBS resize to 250GB:
[image]

IOPS chart after resize:
[image]

Comment: You should also look at the queries that are being replicated -- If, for example, a better index would speed up the queries, then replication might not need so many IOPs.

Comment: Thanks Rick, yes, we have several areas in which we can improve our queries a lot. We also noticed how cheap gp2 volumes are relatively. We have a massive amount of activity on our databases (useful activity!) and have decided to ramp up our EBS volumes significantly - eg from 120GB -> 900GB or so which increases the available IOPS loads :) During the upgrade we could see during the burst period what the app was demanding in terms of IOPS so have used that as a new baseline.

Comment: Hardware upgrades have limits.  Once you hit the limit, hardware upgrades are no longer an option.  I prefer to look for SQL optimizations.  In some cases, I can get 10x speedup -- an improvement rarely possible with hardware.  Sometimes I go back to the application and convince the developers to rethink things.  In rare cases, the result is >100x improvement.

Comment: For further analysis, please provide the settings and status as discussed [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning).

Comment: @RickJames I couldn't agree more about improving queries - however, in this instance we needed a quick fix to simply allow us to have a working replica server so we can take more frequent backups. Code changes are fairly expensive here due to our under-sized team (at the moment). Upgrading the IOPS was relatively extremely cheap which is why we did it. I've also discovered that we can use the multi-threaded slave option as we have several databases on the same server. This should speed things up no end.

Comment: 5.6 has that unfortunate limitation of splitting on DB.  Galera and MySQL 8.0 each got away from that, thereby allowing much better multi-threading.